# How do I refresh a dynamic text field on MouseEvent.CLICK in a one-frame .fla?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, textfield

This is my first post and is probably really dumb.

I have a single-frame actionscript-3 fla file.  When my movie clip is clicked, it fills in a dynamic text field with randomly generated text. (Basically, it's an insult button.) It only works the first time, though. How do I make it refresh the text on each click?

Comment: You should enhance your question adding your code, it helps us to answer it within your own example.

Answer (score 0):

If the TextField is generated programmatically you should try re-applying the TextFormat. I find I have to do this for AS generated TextFields when I update the text.